# Como fazer um elemento continuar com efeito ao passar o mouse em outro?

Tags: html5, css3

Tenho o seguinte código:

```css
  .classes {
  margin-top: 80px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: red;
}

.classes ul {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
}

.classes ul li {
  position: relative;
}

.classes button {
  display: block;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
}

.classes ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  border-left: 3px solid black;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.classes ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

.classes button {
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #7D8A9B;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
}

.classes .sessoes {
  border: none;
}


/*Móveis*/

.sessao1:hover {
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #7ec8fc;
}

.moveis:hover {
  background-color: #7ec8fc;
  color: white;
}


/*Roupas*/

.sessao2:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #82edaa;
}

.roupas:hover {
  background-color: #82edaa;
}


/*Outros*/

.sessao3:hover {
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #f34f4f;
}

.outros:hover {
  background-color: #f34f4f;
  color: white;
}


/*Cozinha*/

.sessao4:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #E6E0D4;
}

.cozinha:hover {
  backgr
```

```html
<nav class="classes">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <!-- Sessão dos Móveis -->
      <button class="sessao1">Móveis</button>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <button class="sessoes moveis" id="linkCadeira" onclick="cadeira()">Cadeiras</button>

        </li>
        <li>
          <button class="sessoes moveis" onclick="mesas()">Mesas</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button class="sessoes moveis" onclick="sofas()">Sofásas</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button class="sessoes moveis" onclick="instantes()">Instantes</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button class="sessoes moveis" onclick="armarios()">Armarios</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <!-- Sessão das Roupas -->
      <button class="sessao2">Roupas</button>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <button class="sessoes roupas" onclick="bones()">Bonés</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button class="sessoes roupas" onclick="camisas()">Camisas</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button class="sessoes roupas" onclick="shorts()">Shorts</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button class="sessoes roupas" onclick="calcados()">Calçados</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <!-- Sessão dos Outros -->
      <button class="sessao3">Outros</button>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <button class="sessoes outros" onclick="quadros()">Quadros</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button class="sessoes outros" onclick="abajur()">Abajur</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button class="sessoes outros" onclick="luminarias()">Luminárias</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button class="sessoes outros" onclick="tapetes()">Tapetes</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <!-- Sessão dos Itens de Cozinha -->
      <button class="sessao4">Itens de Cozinha</button>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <button class="sessoes cozinha" onclick="panelas()">Panelas</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button class="sessoes cozinha" onclick="talheres()">Talheres</button>

        </li>
        <li>
          <button class="sessoes cozinha" onclick="fogoes()">Fogões</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button class="sessoes cozinha" onclick="microondas()">Microondas</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

E quero saber se é possível e se for como posso fazer com que o efeito do hover dos botões principais permaneça ao passar o mouse por cima dos botões secundários, pois quando se passa o mouse por cima dos "subItens" o efeito dos itens principais some.
Obs: Somente com html e css, se não for possível mostrar outra solução.

Comment: Por quê utilizar `button`? Acho que utilizar `a` ficará mais semântico para um menu.

Comment: Estou utilizando esse menu lateral com buttons pois se observa eles tem uma função onClick que faz aparecer uma div e sumir com outra caso já esteja aparecendo, se eu fosse utilizar a tag "a" teria que colocar dentro do href um "#" fazendo com que o usuário voltasse para o topo do site ao clicar ou então colocar "javascript:;" dentro do href o que deixaria o código obstrutivo, o qual nenhuma das duas opções ficariam viável.

Comment: Até onde sei, não é possível usando apenas css, você terá que recorrer a javascript para adicionar/remover as classes corretas ao elemento pai. Já ouvi que daria para fazer apenas com CSS utilizando `pointer-events`, mas não tenho certeza.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O único problema no seu CSS é que você faz o efeito sobre o `:hover` do botão e quando o *mouse* está sobre o sub-menu, o botão perde a propriedade `hover`. A solução mais simples é passar o efeito para o `:hover` do elemento `li` imediatamente acima do botão. Ou seja, enquanto atualmente você faz:

```
<li>
  <button class="sessao1" ...>
  ...
</li>
```

Você precisará fazer:

```
<li class="sessao1">
  <button ...>
  ...
</li>
```

E no CSS, alterar os estilos de:

```
.sessao1:hover {
  ...
}
```

Para:

```
.sessao1:hover > button {
  ...
}
```

Ainda, para manter o coloração branca da fonte no sub-menu, você pode separar os dois estilos, tal como em:

```
.classes button:hover {
  color: white;
}

.sessao1:hover > button {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #7ec8fc;
}
```

Desta forma o efeito `hover` permanece enquanto o *mouse* estiver no sub-menu e todos os botões dentro de `.classes` ficarão com a fonte branca ao passar o *mouse*. No estilo de `.sessao1` restará apenas o estilo da borda, que é único para cada elemento. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```css
.classes {
  margin-top: 80px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: red;
}

.classes ul {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
}

.classes ul li {
  position: relative;
}

.classes button {
  display: block;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
}

.classes button:hover {
  color: white;
}

.classes ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  border-left: 3px solid black;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.classes ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

.classes button {
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #7D8A9B;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
}

.classes .sessoes {
  border: none;
}


/*Móveis*/

.sessao1:hover > button {
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #7ec8fc;
}

.moveis:hover {
  background-color: #7ec8fc;
  color: white;
}


/*Roupas*/

.sessao2:hover > button {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #82edaa;
}

.roupas:hover {
  background-color: #82edaa;
}


/*Outros*/

.sessao3:hover > button {
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #f34f4f;
}

.outros:hover > button {
  background-color: #f34f4f;
  color: white;
}


/*Cozinha*/

.sessao4:hover > hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #E6E0D4;
}
```

```html
<nav class="classes">
  <ul>
    <li class="sessao1">
      <!-- Sessão dos Móveis -->
      <button>Móveis</button>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <button class="sessoes moveis" id="linkCadeira" onclick="cadeira()">Cadeiras</button>

        </li>
        <li>
          <button class="sessoes moveis" onclick="mesas()">Mesas</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button class="sessoes moveis" onclick="sofas()">Sofásas</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button class="sessoes moveis" onclick="instantes()">Instantes</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button class="sessoes moveis" onclick="armarios()">Armarios</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="sessao2">
      <!-- Sessão das Roupas -->
      <button>Roupas</button>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <button class="sessoes roupas" onclick="bones()">Bonés</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button class="sessoes roupas" onclick="camisas()">Camisas</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button class="sessoes roupas" onclick="shorts()">Shorts</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button class="sessoes roupas" onclick="calcados()">Calçados</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="sessao3">
      <!-- Sessão dos Outros -->
      <button>Outros</button>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <button class="sessoes outros" onclick="quadros()">Quadros</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button class="sessoes outros" onclick="abajur()">Abajur</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button class="sessoes outros" onclick="luminarias()">Luminárias</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button class="sessoes outros" onclick="tapetes()">Tapetes</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="sessao4">
      <!-- Sessão dos Itens de Cozinha -->
      <button>Itens de Cozinha</button>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <button class="sessoes cozinha" onclick="panelas()">Panelas</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button class="sessoes cozinha" onclick="talheres()">Talheres</button>

        </li>
        <li>
          <button class="sessoes cozinha" onclick="fogoes()">Fogões</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button class="sessoes cozinha" onclick="microondas()">Microondas</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

> **Nota:** seu CSS está bem confuso. Pelo o que vi, você está aplicando o estilo duas vezes à `.classes button` e, assim, o segundo sobrescreverá o primeiro. Tome cuidado com isso.

Answer (score 1):

Eu apenas fiz uma concatenação do css, como eu trabalho mais com front e back-end ficou mais facil de achar a solução somente com o css, ai consigo trabalhar vários elementos iguais com estilos diferentes, o código ficou assim:

```
.classes > ul > li:hover > button {
    color: #fff;
}
.classes > ul > li > ul > li > button{
  color: #000;
}
.classes > ul > li > ul > li > button:hover{
  color: #fff;
}
```

Espero ter ajudado. :)